# One periodic cohomology theories?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there a classification of one periodic cohomology theories? In other words, spaces $X$ such that $\Omega X \simeq X$? For example, $X=*$ and $X= K(G,0) \times K(G,1) \times \dots$ are examples. More generally, if $\{Y_n\}$ is an Omega spectrum $X=\dots \times Y_1 \times Y_0 \times \Omega Y_0 \times \dots$ is an example.

I ask because I have a space (related to stable block bundles) which does not seem like it should be contractible but appears to be its own loop space.

Comment: Is there any additional structure you're putting on these? I'm skeptical that there's a classification of such things without any additional conditions imposed. For what it's worth, a sort of "universal" example can be obtained as the Thom spectrum of the inclusion Z -> Pic(S^0) = Z x BGL_1(S^0). The connective cover of this spectrum is ΩS^2_+, and so it is an E_1-ring spectrum, but I don't think it has more structure than that. (That's one reason why 2-periodic things are nicer: the Thom spectrum of Z = Ω^2 CP^oo -> Ω^2 BU = BU x Z is an E_2-ring spectrum, whose connective cover is ΩS^3_+.)

Comment: @skd I wasn't aware of any nontrivial examples, so I mostly wanted to know if anyone was automatically boring. Interestingly, it did come up in conjunction with $Pic(S^0)$ which I don't know anything about. Do you have any reference for basic facts about $Pic(S^0)$. Particularly its relation to the J-homomorphism.

Comment: You can think of the J-homomorphism as the geometric realization of the (symmetric monoidal) functor N(Vect_R) -> Pic(S^0), where Vect_R is the category of finite-dimensional real vector spaces and linear isomorphisms, sending V to its one-point compactification S^V. There is a weak equivalence N(Vect_R) = Z x BO. Note that Pic(S^0) = Z x BGL_1(S^0), and the J-homomorphism sends the Z to Z (because the one-point compactification of R is S^1, the generator of the Picard group of Sp), and BO -> BGL_1(S^0) sends a bundle to the associated spherical fibration. Not sure of a reference, though.

Comment: @skd : aren't you supposed to group-complete N(Vect_R) before you get Z x BO ?

Comment: These "1-periodic spectra" are exactly the modules over $S[t^\pm1]$, the free associative ring spectrum on one invertible generator in degree 1. Dunno how helpful this observation is

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Yes, sorry about that. Note that Denis' associative ring spectrum is exactly the Thom spectrum in my first comment.

Comment: This doesn't help you to get a classification, but a simple way to construct a 1-periodic spectra is to take a 2-periodic spectrum $X$ and take wedge with its suspension.

Comment: The question reminds me of the fact that real-oriented cohomology theories are much less interesting than complex-oriented ones, owing to the fact that $MO$ is an $H\mathbb F_2$ module. I think maybe a reasonable precisification of the question would be to ask whether every 1-periodic spectrum is of the form described by @user43326 above. I think this is equivalent to asking something like whether $\mathbb S[t_1^{\pm 1}]$ splits as $\mathbb S[t_2^{\pm 1}] \vee\Sigma \mathbb S[t_2^{\pm 1}]$, where $t_i$ is a free generator in degree $i$.